# Typescript. KnockoutJs. Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, npm

Currently I am following [official ts-ko demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/knockout.html). When I put a direct reference to Ko:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/knockout/index.d.ts" />
```

There is no errors. But when a refrence is added in the following way:

```
import * as ko from "knockout";
```

an error is thrown:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Typescript demo [states](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/knockout.html) that:

> We’ll need to grab Knockout itself, as well as something called RequireJS.

What is the right way to define RequireJs? Why it is required to use requirejs for "import" case?

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.33",
    "knockout": "3.4.0",
    "@types/knockout": "1.1.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From RequireJs [homepage](http://requirejs.org/).
RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader.

> What is the right way to define RequireJs?

You can just reference your RequireJs from a script tag.

```
<script src="scripts/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and define your requireJs configuration.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'app',
    paths: {
        text: "../scripts/text" //Path to text.js, you will use this to load html that will be used in your ko components,
        widgets: "widgets",
        app: "."
    }
});
```

Then you can register your component just like this one.

```
ko.components.register(name, {
    viewModel: { require: path },
    template: { require: 'text!'+ path +'.html' }
});
```

> Why it is required to use requirejs for "import" case?

In order to load your ko components asynchronously, you need a module loader like RequireJs. See this [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html).

Comment: Tutorial on requirejs:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRqsZqLyYaU
Folder structure for require js:
https://github.com/volojs/create-template